# Getting matrix from pandas DataFrame: stuck to dtype object

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

How can we extract pandas.DataFrame values as a matrix, when the DataFrame has to be initialized without any values (because the dimensionality of each column is then unknown):

For example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame()
df = df.append(dict(foo=np.ones(2), bar=np.ones(3)), ignore_index=True)  # without ignore it crashes
df = df.append(dict(foo=np.zeros(2), bar=np.zeros(3)), ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Out:

```
          bar              foo
0  [1.0, 1.0]  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1  [0.0, 0.0]  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I have difficulties getting the data of each column (`bar`, `foo`) as a numpy matrix that I could slice (ideally: df['bar'][:, 2]). Indeed, it currently remains a numpy array with dtype=object.

```
df['foo'].as_matrix()
Out: array([array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: In your initial code sample, there is no "bar", but there is a "bar" in your output and second code sample. I think you might have a typo in that first code snippet? Also, df.append() does not occur in place unless you specify that kwarg. Did you intend to do df = df.append(...

Comment: My bad, I edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the way you're doing your initialization, you're not actually creating a DataFrame of values, but are instead creating a DataFrame of numpy arrays, as you can see by looking at `df.shape`, which is (2,1) rather than (2,3).

It's unclear to me what you actually want the array to be, as you're starting by creating a column named foo that has one value (the array). If you wanted to create the DataFrame as it appears (a 2x3 array) you'd need to do something more like the following:

```
df = DataFrame(np.zeros((1,3)))
df = df.append( DataFrame(np.ones((1,3))), ignore_index=True )
```

Now you can just do `df.ix[:,1]`, or `df.as_matrix()`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have several columns (`foo`, `bar`) with different dimensions: e.g: `df['foo'].shape = (n, 2)` and `df['bar'].shape = (n, 3)`, where n is `len(df)`. I edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: Then that's not a DataFrame. DataFrames are 2d.

Comment: Ok, thank. Does pandas has an object than would have this function?

Comment: With different dimensions? No. Why wouldn't you just use multiple dataframes?

Comment: Because each row of foo and bar correspond to the same sample.